# Setting HTTP User-Agent header with requests-oauthlib

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) library to get a request token from an OAuth (v1) provider.

```
oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                      signature_method=SIGNATURE_HMAC,
                      signature_type=SIGNATURE_TYPE_AUTH_HEADER)

resp = oauth.fetch_request_token(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
```

I'd like to send a custom `User-Agent` header with the request token fetch request and include some contact information in case there are ever any problems with my script. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to pass in a client class to the `OAuth1Session` constructor. From the docblock in the relevant file:

```
"""
    :param client_class: A subclass of `oauthlib.oauth1.Client` to use with
                         `requests_oauthlib.OAuth1` instead of the default
"""
```

Within the oauthlib.oauth1.Client class, the `_render(self, request, formencode=False, realm=None)` method appears responsible for preparing the request. Since unrelated headers [don't impact](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1) the base string that the request signature is created from, adding a new header/changing an existing User-Agent header shouldn't cause the signature to change in any way.

As such, we can create a custom client class, override the `_render` method and call the implementation in the parent class once we've added our header:

```
class CustomClient(Client):
    def _render(self, request, formencode=False, realm=None):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = "FooClient/1.0"
        return super()._render(request, formencode, realm)
```

The code that instantiates `OAuth1Session` then simply needs to reference the above class:

```
oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                          signature_method=SIGNATURE_HMAC,
                          signature_type=SIGNATURE_TYPE_AUTH_HEADER, client_class=CustomClient)
```

Comment: timestamp difference between question and answer is ZERO second!

Comment: That's probably because I ticked the handy checkbox which let me post the question and answer at the same time :P